# Crear un objecto FormData no obtiene un input de tipo select multiple

Tags: javascript, html-select, formdata

Al crear un objecto FormData pasándole un formulario, detecto que si tengo un input de tipo select con el atributo multiple para poder seleccionar varios elementos, el objeto FormData solo gestiona un valor.

Aquí un ejemplo muy sencillo.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form)));
});
```

```html
 <form action="">
   <input type="text" name="input-text" />
   
   <select name="input-select[]" multiple>
     <option value="value 1">Value 1</option>
     <option value="value 2" selected>Value 2</option>
     <option value="value 3">Value 3</option>
   </select>
 </form>
 <button>GET</button>
```

¿Habría forma de que el objeto FormData obtendría en el caso del select todos los valores sin tener que hacer append al objeto ni ninguna otro tipo de logica adiccional?

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El form data si tiene todos los valores, lo que pasa es que tú lo conviertes a objeto con `Object.fromEntrie` y un objeto no puede tener repetido el nombre (la clave)

Puedes comprobarlos si haces:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  let formData = new FormData(form);
  
  for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(`${pair[0]}, ${pair[1]}`);
  }
});
```

```html
 <form action="">
   <input type="text" name="input-text" />
   
   <select name="input-select[]" multiple>
     <option value="value 1">Value 1</option>
     <option value="value 2" selected>Value 2</option>
     <option value="value 3">Value 3</option>
   </select>
 </form>
 <button>GET</button>
```